# What happens when you add a where/filter clause on a select view when the view already contains the where/filter clause inside?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I am using a union inside a view and filtering out all items that has `EQ` or `NECF` as shown below:

```
REPLACE VIEW X.VIEW_NAME
AS
LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS
SELECT
*
FROM X.TABLENAME A
WHERE A.SIS <> 'EQ' OR A.SERVICE_NUMBER <> 'NECF'
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM X.TABLENAME B
WHERE B.SIS <> 'EQ' OR B.SERVICE_NUMBER <> 'NECF';
```

Now if I filter on the view again as

```
SEL *
FROM X.VIEWNAME A
WHERE A.SIS = 'EQ' OR A.SERVICE_NUMBER = 'NECF';
```

I do get records! Was not the view supposed to filter out the `EQ` or `NECF`. When I do the second select query on the view, I should have received 0 records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view contains another then you anticipate.

```
...
WHERE A.SIS <> 'EQ'
       OR A.SERVICE_NUMBER <> 'NECF'
...
```

retains a row when `sis` is `'EQ'` but `service_number` isn't `'NECF'` and also when `service_number` is `'NECF'` but `sis` isn't `EQ`. Note that you used the `OR` operator. If you want to filter out any row where `sis` is `'EQ'` or `service_number` is `'NECF'`, you need to use `AND`:

```
...
WHERE A.SIS <> 'EQ'
      AND A.SERVICE_NUMBER <> 'NECF'
...
```

Also note that you can easily see that by using De Morgan's laws:
We want to filter out rows where

```
sis = 'EQ'
 OR service_number = 'NECF'
```

That means we want to retain rows where the negation of that is true (to have that in the `WHERE` clause). And the negation is:

```
sis <> 'EQ'
 AND service_number <> 'NECF'
```

That is negating the operators and change  `OR` to `AND`.

What's also funny is that you do a `UNION ALL` of the same set -- the queries, semantically, are the same (the different aliases change nothing).